# There's a way to compare 1 list with N list? DART

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to take a list and compare if the elements of it are equal to those of another list, if so, I would like it to return an indicator that if they are equal, if not, it will return an indicator that they are not equal. And so do it with an N number of lists.

Comment: You have N lists.  Do you want to compare every pair of lists?  Or do you want to optimize it to only compare once against a cluster of known identical lists?

Comment: One way would be to use Fast Immutable Collections (a pub package) to turn each list into an IList which can be used as Map keys, then do a normal counting of these ILists by incrementing values in the Map based on the IList key.  You'll end up with a count of every combination of Lists, rather efficiently.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz Exactly, I want to compare a main list with N amounts of list and return if it has the same items or not.

Comment: If I get time today, I'll code up an example of my suggested solution.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz that would be nice! appreciate it.